# Wordpress Ajax Load More script not passing a parameter to the wordpress functions file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So, I am creating these pages that need to display a custom query filtered by author. These authors need to be automatic, so the script  I am using for the ajax load more button is not really pulling the posts from the author I have selected, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong... Can anyone help out?

So here is the code for the ajax load more from the functions.php file:

```
function load_colunistasposts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_colunistasposts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $colunista = $_POST['colunista']; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'cat' => 3,
        'author' => $colunista,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
                        <div class="archivePosts" data-aos="zoom-in" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>';">
                            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
                            <div class="archivePostsInner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
                                <div class="gradient">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <small><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></small>
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php
    endif;

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_colunistasposts_by_ajax', 'load_colunistasposts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_colunistasposts_by_ajax', 'load_colunistasposts_by_ajax_callback');
```

Here is the code for my template file. I am using a ACF to get the author for this archive page:

```
<?php $colunista = get_field("selecione_o_colunista");                  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'cat' => 3,
        'author' => $colunista['ID'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => 1,
    );
$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="my-posts">
            <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
<div class="archivePosts" data-aos="zoom-in" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>';">
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
<div class="archivePostsInner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
    <div class="gradient">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <small><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></small></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>          
            <?php  endwhile ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<div class="loadmore"><button>Carregar Mais Notícias</button></div>                 
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
var colunista = <?php echo $colunista['ID']; ?>;    
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_colunistasposts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_colunistasposts"); ?>'
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.my-posts').append(response);
            page++;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I am trying to pass the author id to the code in the functions.php file, but I am obviously failing.. Could anyone help out???

Answer (score 0):

Why you guys are doing such a lengthy process please use https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/ to get it worked.

In your case use following.

Download jquery-ias.min.js this script from the website mentioned.

Enqueue the script using function, It needs to be enqueued after jQuery.js.

In your template file add this

```
    <?php $colunista = get_field("selecione_o_colunista");  
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;                
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'cat' => 3,
    'author' => $colunista['ID'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="my-posts">
    <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
        <div class="archivePosts" data-aos="zoom-in" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>';">
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
            <div class="archivePostsInner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
                <div class="gradient">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <small><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></small></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <?php  endwhile ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
<div class="pagination">
  <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</div>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();   
?>
```

After that in your function.php add this code to add class to next_posts_link.

```
/*Add class to next and previous post for load more*/
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes');
function posts_link_attributes() {
    return 'class="next"';
}
```

After that, Create one JS file and enqueue it and add below things in that file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var ias = $.ias({
        item: '.archivePosts',
        container: '.my-posts',
        pagination: '.pagination',
        next:       '.next'
    });

    ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({
      text: 'More >'
    }));
    /*No article left text*/
    ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
      text: 'No more Articles.', // optionally
    }));
    /*Spinner URL*/
    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
      src: siteUrl + '/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images/loading4.gif' // optionally
    }));
});
```

Let me know if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, however it doesn't seem to work. I have added everything you told me to, but it just won't work, here is my test page:

http://www.osul.com.br/burd-test/

Is there any way you could just say which part of my code is not passing the author id to the functions file? Cause that script is working on other parts of the site, I just need it to filter by author in this particular part...

Comment: Please check the console. You have error "$.ias is not a function" you just need to replace $ with jQuery.

Comment: Also, It seems like you have not included this js jquery-ias.min.js.